# Fetching the commits between two jenkins build

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, cicd

I have my jenkins job running every two hours. So between the builds there are commits.
Please let me know if there a way to filter out the commits between two build.
My final aim would be to send an email to the author of the commit , about the build status.

I did try "last changes" plugin and other few possible ways but nothing worked.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For a single repository with a single build, something like this shell command should do the trick:

```
git log $GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT..$GIT_COMMIT
```

If you have monorepo instead (several independent builds going in the same repo), you can look at Reliza Hub (my project) and corresponding plugin - https://plugins.jenkins.io/reliza-integration/ - this would populate env.LATEST_COMMIT for you for each project. So that your log statement would instead be something like:

```
git log $LATEST_COMMIT..$GIT_COMMIT --date=iso-strict --pretty="%H|||%ad|||%s|||%an|||%ae"
```

There is a more detailed sample how to set it up on the plugin page.

Comment: I need the details of a single repository and the repo is associated only with a single build job. The git command you post did not work , I am not pro-efficient with jenkins, I am pasting below the the trail script which I ran in jenkins . Please help.

``

Comment: `
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Git clone') {
            steps {
               git credentialsId: '******'
            heythere()
            script{
                sh label: '', script: 'git log $GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT..$GIT_COMMIT'
              }

            }
        }
    }
}
`

I get the below error:

fatal: ..: '..' is outside repository

Comment: Seems like you are having separate step for git clone, so you're cloning into subpath - make sure to cd into that subpath directory in that case before running git log command.